# Return Soundcloud tracks list by user ID

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I am working on a website for a DJ and I have to make a player. To get it, I would like to get all the tracks from the user, then make streaming player with these one.

I tried a lot of code and the last try is the nearest I've done, but it not returns the good tracks. I don't know where the tracks come from, but it is not the one from the user I want.

Here is my code :

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: "17f834e2f3c8ef63fa411ef6942caf0f"
});

SC.get('/resolve', {
    url: 'https://soundcloud.com/stormthedj'
}, function(user) {
    theUserID = user.id;
});

SC.get("/tracks", {
    user_id: theUserID,
    limit: 100
}, function (tracks) {

for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
    console.log(tracks[i].title);
}
```

Thank you in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with SoundCloud's JavaScript API, but I'm assuming it's asynchronous. In that case, move the `tracks` call into the callback passed to the `resolve` call.

```
SC.get('/resolve', {
    url: 'https://soundcloud.com/stormthedj'
}, function(user) {
    var theUserID = user.id;

    SC.get("/tracks", {
        user_id: theUserID,
        limit: 100
    }, function (tracks) {

      for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
          console.log(tracks[i].title);
      }
    }
});
```

---

Note that promise libraries such as [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) can help keep chains of callbacks such as the one above more manageable.

Comment: Yeah this code works perfectly! Thank you! But I had to correct it, there was a missing ")"

Comment: There is only one problem. I cannot put these values in a variable. When I output them in the console.log, I see them correctly, but when I push them in an array and output it out of the SC function, I just get an empty array. What is wrong? In the for loop, I use this code `tracksList.push(tracks[i].title);`

Comment: That depends on exactly how you're trying to do it (hint: please provide a _complete_ code example) but I'm guessing it's the same problem as before. These methods are **asynchronous** which means that **anything** that depends on a value in the callback must happen within the callback, or after the callback executes.